# Can not Update Field Type Attachment MS Access

Tags: c#, winforms

It can Select data from ms access and show gridview but It can not update field type Attachment.

```
string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\500.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=";

using (OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
{
    MyConn.Open();
    var StrCmd = "UPDATE ข้อมูลรถ SET รูปรถ = @p2 WHERE ลำดับ = @p1";
    OleDbCommand oldcommand = new OleDbCommand(StrCmd, MyConn);
    byte[] pic = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\test.png");

    oldcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    oldcommand.CommandText = StrCmd;
    oldcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", pic);
    oldcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "1");

    try
    {
        oldcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Used Code

```
var StrCmd = "UPDATE ข้อมูลรถ SET สี = @p2 WHERE ลำดับ = @p1";
```

it could update another field.but only รูปรถ field can't update.

use code

```
var StrCmd = "UPDATE ข้อมูลรถ SET รูปรถ.Value = @p2 WHERE ลำดับ.Value = @p1";
```

can't execute and Error >>
"No value given for one or more required parameters."

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You first need determine the primary key `value` for your column. Then change your query to the following:

```
var StrCmd = "UPDATE ข้อมูลรถ SET รูปรถ.Value = @p2 WHERE ลำดับ.Value = @p1";
```

Further reading here [Using multivalued fields in queries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6f64f92d-659f-411c-9503-b6624e1e323a?CTT=5&origin=HA001233722&CorrelationId=a25b336c-c0e3-4913-8485-a0f8718046c5&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bm8)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var StrCmd = "UPDATE ข้อมูลรถ SET รูปรถ.Value = @p2 WHERE ลำดับ.Value = @p1";
```